# Javascript Human Readable Data Format

Tags: php, ruby, json, node.js

TLDR; I need a tree of likely complicated strings, read from a file and turned into an object in javascript. My question being, is there a good standard format out there that works across most languages or an easy function that can do this commonly with a standard file format (eg. ini files)?

I want to store some data in a user readable file format, so I can edit it with a text editor easily. Lots of regular expressions so there can be many backslashes, new lines, quotes, brackets and everything that I don't want to have to write like this:

```
{
    "(html|php|pl|cgi|bak|sh|js)$": {
        "report": "/(\\$.{3}\\[10\\]
            |letcaro\\.com
            |zbUVSfJ\
            |<\\?php[ \t]{10}
            |l\\(base64_decode
            |eval\\s*\\(base64_decode\\s*\\(
            |base64_decode\\(\\$_POST
            |@error_reporting\\(0\\)
            |web shell
...
```

As you can see there are a whole lot of double backslashes and this isn't valid json already as there are new lines at the end giving us 'invalid control character' errors if we attempt to process it as is with json. We could load this as a string, then run a process over it (replace new lines with \n or some such) and get where we are going but it's going to get worse as this file grows.

This system is running as a single simple node js file that doesn't need any dependencies so I want to avoid setting up an installer chain to pull in an xml parser through npm or bowser or anything like that. Worst case scenario I could get by with storing the key as a filename and the contents of the filename as the value. That would be a huge overhead and mess to maintain.

YAML (which sounds marvelous and would work wonders here) requires external dependencies.
XML (cdata for regex values and tags for keys would be wonderful) requires external dependencies.

Side note: I'll also be re-writing this in other languages, php (which can use json_parse) and ruby (maybe require a gem for JSON.parse) so language agnostic would be very nice.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your gross strings in a plaintext file, or really anywhere where the text is exactly as you need it.

   ```
   /(\$.{3}\[10\]
   |letcaro\.com
   |zbUVSfJ\
   |<\?php[ \t]{10}
   |l\(base64_decode
   |eval\s*\(base64_decode\s*\(
   |base64_decode\(\$_POST
   |@error_reporting\(0\)
   |web shell/
   ```
2. Load it and encode it. [PHP]

   ```
   $text = file_get_contents("derp.txt");
   echo json_encode($text);
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   "\/(\\$.{3}\\[10\\]\n|letcaro\\.com\n|zbUVSfJ\\\n|<\\?php[ \\t]{10}\n|l\\(base64_decode\n|eval\\s*\\(base64_decode\\s*\\(\n|base64_decode\\(\\$_POST\n|@error_reporting\\(0\\)\n|web shell\/\n"
   ```

You're going to drive yourself nuts trying to maintain a single, human-readable file full of data containing special characters. Write your data as intended, then use a JSON library to encode it.

Comment: The problem I had with this, is that I have to then have my uncompiled system, then make a script that compiles it all into json, then have the finished product. What I'm leaning towards doing is writing a new file format, that just uses a number of whitespace characters at the start of a line to define depth, then crawl through that with a single simple function to create my object. This function I'll rewrite in other languages (fairly language agnostic and does not rely on third party libraries possibly then) that is if I can finish this function.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I don't personally know of any standardized methods to accomplish what you are looking to do. From a ruby perspective, my first go to solutions would have been either JSON or YAML. Both of which require some small external dependencies. If you want to keep this language agnostic and exclude any external dependencies, the only solution that comes to mind is along the lines of storing the information in a file (like you mentioned). But you are still going to need a way to parse it, so if you dont want external dependencies, you would need to write your own parser code in each language you wanted to use the file in. I would go with Sammitch's approach honestly though. Let JSON do all the hard work.

Comment: Definitely added to a file, this will be stored basically as a large string. I'm leaning more towards writing a parser in each language.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just invented a new file format.

Here's my test data...

```
Root
    Child 1
        Value of
        this child can be
        whatever in a multitude
        of lines that won't end up getting
        added as a key because it is a leaf.
    Child 2
        Sub Child 1
            This is a deeper item that is a leaf so it also won't become a key.
        Sub Child 2
            A second sub-child that should become a leaf too.
end
```

Here's my terribly innefecient and ugly parser for this file...

```
function parseTabTree(data) {
    var root = { value: 'root' }, obj = root, current = '', lines = data.split('\r\n'), curDepth = -1;
    for (ix in lines) {
        var line = lines[ix].replace(/^\s+/, '');
        var depth = lines[ix].match(/^[\s]*/g)[0].length;
        // Shallow, push our current value in and switch target up a level.
        if (depth < curDepth) {
            obj.value = current;
            for (var cl = curDepth - depth; cl > 0; --cl) obj = obj.parent;
            last = current = '';
        }
        // Deep, push our current target to parent and step down a level.
        else if (depth > curDepth) {
            nobj = {parent: obj, value: current};
            if (!obj[current]) obj[current] = [];
            obj[current].push(nobj);
            obj = nobj;
            current = '';
        }
        // Across
        else obj.value += current;
        current += line;
        curDepth = depth;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Here's how I use it in node...

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('test.txt', function (err, data) {
    obj = parseTabTree(data.toString());
    console.log(util.inspect(obj, false, null));
});
```

And finally, my satisfactory output!

```
{ value: 'root',
  '':
  [ { parent: [Circular],
   value: 'test',
   Root:
    [ { parent: [Circular],
        value: 'Root',
        'Child 1':
         [ { parent: [Circular],
             value: 'Value ofthis child can bewhatever in a multitudeof lines that won\'t end up gettingadded as a key because it is a leaf.' } ],
        'Child 2':
         [ { parent: [Circular],
             value: 'Child 2',
             'Sub Child 1':
              [ { parent: [Circular],
                  value: 'This is a deeper item that is a leaf so it also won\'t become a key.' } ],
             'Sub Child 2':
              [ { parent: [Circular],
                  value: 'A second sub-child that should become a leaf too.' } ] } ] } ] } ] }
```

There are still some flaws like having multiple leaves for a single branch or having to place something at the end of the file (which could be easily fixed) but more or less it seems to be working! Now I can make simplified regex checks at the top and make them more complicated as they get deeper.

I put everything in a git repo in case anyone wants to use it or improve on it!

https://github.com/Xedecimal/tabtree